# source not working from within shell script

Tags: shell

I have the following line in a shell script:

```
source bash_profile
```

It does not error, but it does not do anything that I can see either (It's not reloading my aliases like I expect)

However, from the same folder that the shell script is in, if I just run the command from the shell, it works like I expect.

I never change directories from within the script either. In fact, here is the script:

```
direction="to"
destination="local"
if [ -n $1 ]
    then
    direction=$1
fi
if [ -n $2 ]
    then
    destination=$2
fi

command=$direction$destination

if [ $command = "fromlocal" -o $command = "togit" ]
    then
    cp /c/Program\ Files/Git/etc/bash_profile /d/automata/flgitscripts/bash_profile
else
    cp /d/automata/flgitscripts/bash_profile /c/Program\ Files/Git/etc/bash_profile
fi

source /c/Program\ Files/Git/etc/bash_profile
```

I use the script to manage changes to and from the bash_profile and store them in a git repo.

Why isn't the source command working from within the shell script?

Comment: Are you sourcing the script too: `source thescriptname`? Otherwise the script is running in a new shell and the `source bash_profile` command is affect that new shell (which exits at the end of the script).

Comment: Put this as the answer and I will accept. I was running the script just by typing the script name "theScript.sh" instead of typing "source theScript.sh". Thanks!

Comment: You have to say @Bert or he might never see it.

Comment: Thanks @Dennis Williamson for the @ poke :-)    @cmcculloh - comment posted as answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Are you sourcing the script too: `source thescriptname`? Otherwise the script is running in a new shell and the `source bash_profile` command affects that new shell (which exits at the end of the script).