# Python pyvenv - How do I call "source ~/py33/bin/activate" to activate Python3.3.3 pyvenv Virtual Environment from BASH Script?

Tags: bash, python-3.x, virtualenv

I'm trying to write a BASH script on a ubuntu 12.04 LTS Server to activate a Python virtual environment which was setup using pyvenv.  I wrote the following script (total noob, sorry) and everything works except the "source" command.  What ridiculous thing am I doing wrong?  The virtual environment works fine from the command line.

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello World!!"
source /home/kenny/py33/bin/activate
cat ~/bin/py33.sh
```

I even changed to absolute path (as above) and didn't work.  My script is in ~/bin with "chmod +x" and the PATH includes this directory.  The script is working as is evident from the other elements executing; but, the virtual Python environment (pyvenv) is not activated via "source /home/kenny/py33/bin/activate".

Any ideas?  -- Thank you.

Comment: Just source your script. If it's named py33.sh, then run `. py33.sh`, where the lead `. ` is shorthand for `source`. Your script doesn't need to be executable, doesn't need a shebang, and doesn't need a .sh extension. It is literally *sourced* in the current shell.

Comment: That's a new one for me.  Thank you.  Worked perfectly from an directory.

Comment: Now that I understand "source" and "." I'm confused as to why running a script with "source" as a command didn't work.  Isn't that the same as calling source source ...

Comment: When you executed the script it was running in a new shell (bash, per the shebang), but the point is to modify the environment of the current shell.

Comment: I didn't realize they stacked.  Thank you.  It makes sense now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [source not working from within shell script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380595/source-not-working-from-within-shell-script)